# Managing 3 states in ngFor async

Tags: angular

I'm trying to manage 3 states in my template: Loading, Empty, Error

I have a standard service:

```
public getNews(): Observable<News[]> {
    return this.http.get<News[]>(`${environment.api}/news`);
}
```

In the component I declare the observable and an error state:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.news$ = this.newsService.getNews()
    .pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        this.loadingError = true;
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
}
```

Now in the template I subscribe to the observable with async and manage loading and error states with `ngIf as`

```
    <div class="news-feed" *ngIf="news$ | async as news; else observing">
      <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of news; even as even" [ngClass]="{'even' : even }">
        <h2>
          {{item.title}}
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ng-template #observing>
      <div class="news-feed" *ngIf="!loadingError">
        <div class="item">
          <h2>Loading</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="news-feed" *ngIf="loadingError">
        <div class="item">
          <h2>Http Error</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

This already looks very clumsy with the duplicated divs. How do I add an empty state to display a custom message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditions in the mustache syntax to avoid duplicating your markup for loading and an error.

If you wish to display a message like "No news" when the `news` array is empty, you can use [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet).

```
<div class="news-feed" *ngIf="news$ | async as news; else observing">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of news; even as even" [ngClass]="{'even' : even }">
        <h2>
            {{item.title}}
        </h2>
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="news.length === 0">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="observing; context: { $implicit: true }"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</div>
<ng-template #observing let-empty>
    <div class="news-feed">
        <div class="item">
            <h2>{{loadingError ? 'Http Error' : empty ? 'No New' : 'Loading'}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

See the [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbyk5r).

Comment: okay, this solves the duplicate divs, but the empty state? It feels I need to subscribe to the observable inside the component...

Comment: What do you mean by "empty state"? When there are no news?

Comment: when news[] is empty

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet should be helpful. Let me check

Comment: ok, I can just add a div *ngIf="!news.length"> in the place of the first ng-container and I don't need the nested containers and the rest, but It duplicates the div... I'll definitely subscribe in the .ts, angular doesn't give me much choice...